# How to add LibSVM class to WEKA classpath on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, weka

I am running Max OS X 10.7 Lion and I want to use WEKA with LibSVM from command line.  I get this error:

```
Problem evaluating classifier: libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH!
```

[image: Error I am receiving in WEKA]

I found the LibSVM library [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#download). I need to add it to my Java classpath so that WEKA can find it.  The download contains several files, shown below. I don't know how to add them to my classpath for Java.

[image: Files in LibSVM download that need to be added to classpath]

I am attempting to use the LibSVM classifier in WEKA because it is preferable for me over SMO. I am also unsure if this means the Java classpath or if it is specific to WEKA. I also don't know where to get these classes from. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: LibSVM must be Downloaded, extracted and added to the classpath so that your java program can use it.  See  https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM  for instructions on how to add it to the classpath.  If those instructions are too high level, then you need to put this machine learning business on hold and go straight back to Java beginner walkthroughs on the foundations of Java programming: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java.html It's all those: "Learn Java in 23.7 minutes!" titled books have taught people they can be experts in Java in an hour, when in reality it's closer 5 years.

Comment: WEKA is a GUI application. At the time I was using it because I *didn't* need to know Java to use it (allegedly). These days I'm quite content with Python (NLTK and scikit-learn) and R.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another extremely easy way to add LibSVM support to WEKA on OS X (no command line needed):

1. Download LibSVM from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm+zip)
2. Go to /Applications folder on your Mac (the folder where the Weka app is installed)
3. Right click on Weka > Chose "Show Package Contents"
4. Copy libsvm.jar to /Applications/Weka.app/Contents/Resources/Java
5. open /Applications/Weka.app/Contents/Info.plist in your favorite text editor
6. change `<string>$JAVAROOT/weka.jar</string>` to `<string>$JAVAROOT/weka.jar:$JAVAROOT/libsvm.jar</string>` (you can also adjust the heap size here)
7. Save and start weka

Comment: Thank you for solving but I have a problem is including this one "evaluating classifier rand". How can I handle it?

Answer (score 11):

You can put `libsvm.jar` in a folder of your choice, e.g. `~/Library/Java`, and then run weka from the command-line as follows:

```
$ java -Xmx512m -classpath /Users/chl/weka/weka.jar:/Library/Java/libsvm.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

You can also update your `CLASSPATH` to reflect locations where `*.jar` files can be found. I have the following in my `.profile`:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/chl/weka/weka.jar:~/Library/Java/*"
```

(You will need to replace `/Users/chl/weka` to reflect the correct location of your `weka.jar`; usually, it is located at the top of the directory if you downloaded the source files, or under `weka-3-7-3.app/Contents/Resources/Java/` if you use the bundled app.)

This way, the first command to start weka GUI simplifies to

```
$ java -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar:libsvm.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

Don't use `java -jar` since it will override the `CLASSPATH`, as discussed [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM).

I also have an alias in my `.bash_aliases` for wrapping all that stuff:

```
alias weka='java -Xmx512m -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar'
```

in order to use weka from the command-line as, e.g.

```
$ weka weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -t iris.arff -i
```

Comment: @DanO'Day Did you have a chance to try the above. Did that work?

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to this. Yes, this worked great! Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

1) Copy `libsvm.jar` found [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm) into the Java folder in the package content of the Weka.app:

```
<path-to-Weka.app>/Weka.app/Contents/Java/
```

2) Add this line to your .bash_profile or similar configuration file:

```
export CLASSPATH="<path-to-Weka.app>/Weka.app/Contents/Java/weka.jar:<path-to-Weka.app>/Weka.app/Contents/Java/libsvm.jar"
```

Note: you should replace `<path-to-Weka.app>` by your own path. It could look like `/Applications/JavaApp/weka-3-6-11-oracle-jvm.app`.

Answer (score 1):

Download the libsvm files and past them in the working directory of weka.
Now goes to Control Panel->System->Advance System Setting-> and Edit the Environment Variable, Select the Class_Path variable and copy all that path along with the file name.
i.e. C:\Program Files\Weka\Libsvm.jar;
and click ok-ok-ok
and Restart the weka