# Installing WEKA for python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, weka

I have been attempting to install WEKA for python on my macbook and have been running into some trouble.

First, I installed WEKA through macports:

```
sudo port install weka
```

This went smoothly.
Then, in accordance with [the PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/weka), I tried this command:

```
sudo pip install -U https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/tarball/master
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
AssertionError: Weka JAR file /usr/share/java/weka.jar not found. Ensure the file is installed or update your environment's WEKA_JAR_PATH to only include valid locations.
```

To fix this, I downloaded WEKA from [the University of Waikato page](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html), and copied `weka.jar` as follows:

```
sudo cp /Volumes/weka-3-6-10/weka-3-6-10/weka.jar /usr/share/java/
```

Then, running the pip install command again, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Weka JAR file /usr/share/java/libsvm.jar not found. Ensure the file is installed or update your environment's WEKA_JAR_PATH to only include valid locations.
```

How should I go about fixing this error?

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks), if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing some wisdom from [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248090/how-to-add-libsvm-class-to-weka-classpath-on-a-mac), I downloaded `libsvm.zip` from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#download). I then unzipped the archive and copied over `libsvm.jar` as follows:

```
sudo cp libsvm-3.17/java/libsvm.jar /usr/share/java/
```

This seemed to fix the problem, as the pip command worked immediately thereafter:

```
sudo pip install -U https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/tarball/master
```